How to expose port of LXC container in Proxmox?
I have a proxmox server running an LXC container with radicale (a CalDav server).
Everything worked fine while I only used the server in my own LAN.
Now I want to expose the port 5232 to the Internet, because I want to access my calendar from anywhere.
Nut now comes the problem:
If I try to expose it with the ip of the radicale container in my fritz!box router it creates the follwing rule table 
"Proxmox" is my proxmox server ip and "Radicale" is the container ip.
If I try to reach the container directly over my own network ip it works (so nothing wrong with the container), but if I try to use the public ip it doesn't.
This is my Proxmox network tab:

This is my Radicale LXC container network tab:

